# Может ли быть условие выбора join в запросе SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

Так, чтобы в запросе было условие:

```
SELECT * FROM Table IF(cond) LEFT JOIN TB2 ELSE LEFT JOIN TB3
```

Comment: Разумеется нет.  
Знаю, что скорее всего результат не устроит, но можно так:

    select *, if(cond, tb2.value, tb3.value) 
    from table 
      left join tb2 ...
      left join tb3 ...

Поэтому, описывайте задачу, а не часть.

Comment: Примерно этого и хотел. Все дело в том, что в системе существует 2 типа пользователей, разграниченные по 2-м таблицам. И в зависимости от `UserType`, нужно вытягивать данные из одной из них, потому как в таблице `table `храниться только `id` и `UserType`.
___
Лучше было бы, если избежать одной сцепки с table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собирайте запрос на php, исходя из условий.